# Does CKEditor support document mode?

Tags: ckeditor

we need to edit A4 documents online that would be sent to PDF and printer then. With other editors (TinyMCE) we can't get real WYSIWYG, it won't respect A4 page size. Can CKEditor work as Google Docs does, to edit documents as A4 pages ?